# stop resampling in pandas if gaps between two dates is more than some specific condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe. My dataframe contains ID, Time and Value and Gaps(Hr). I am doing re sampling independent to each IDs. Gaps column gives the consecutive time gaps between two different time. I am doing resampling of every 10 mins and I want to stop re sampling if consecutive Gaps is more than 0.86 Hr and return next rows as original and continue the re sampling again when it finds the same conditions.
my gaps conditions fits like this

```
a (abs(a-b))
b  0
```

Sample Data

```
ID,Time,Value,Gaps
1,1523147332607,2,0.3347541666666667
1,1523148537722,5,0.17346666666666666
1,1523149162202,6,1.6252830555555555
1,1523155013221,4,0.33290027777777775
1,1523156211662,7,0.3722580555555556
1,1523157551791,10,0.0
2,1523156211662,5,0.5115911111111111
2,1523158053390,2,0.3405525
2,1523159279379,9,1.3295477777777778
2,1523164065751,3,0.0
```

As you can see, The ID 1 has Gaps of over 0.86 Hr, So My idea is to stop the re sampling at that point. 
Something like this

```
ID,Time,Value,Gaps
1,1523147332607,2,0.3347541666666667
...................................
1,1523148537722,5,0.17346666666666666
...................................
...................................
1,1523149162202,6,1.6252830555555555
```

So, I want to continue re-sampling to this `Time period 1523149162202` and When there is no more sampling to do, I want to return this last rows as original, i.e

```
1,1523149162202,6,1.6252830555555555
```

And after that, I want to continue resampling again from next rows

```
1,1523155013221,4,0.33290027777777775
1,1523156211662,7,0.3722580555555556
1,1523157551791,10,0.0
```

and this continues

For normal resampling for each Ids,

```
 df = df.set_index(['Time'])
 df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, unit='ms')

 df = (df.groupby('ID', axis=0)['Value']
       .resample('10min')
        .mean()
        .groupby(level=0)
        .apply(lambda x: x.interpolate()).reset_index())
```

But How do I track of each re sampling so that I can stop the re sampling when it meets some conditions and return the original rows at the ends for that part of resampling. And then it continues from the next rows again the same criteria. I was thinking to use `np.where` but i am no where near to achieve this. 
Any suggestions ?

Comment: what is you expected output

Comment: @Wen , The pandas handles the actual output because its a resampling but I have  mentioned about my expected output in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way could be by creating a temporary column 'ID_res' in `df`, incrementing number   when you change ID or at the row after the gaps is over 0.86 such as:

```
df.loc[(df['ID'] != df['ID'].shift())| (df['Gaps'].shift() > 0.86),'ID_res'] = 1
df['ID_res'] = df['ID_res'].cumsum().ffill()
```

so your df looks like:

```
                         ID  Value      Gaps  ID_res
Time                                                
2018-04-08 00:28:52.607   1      2  0.334754     1.0
2018-04-08 00:48:57.722   1      5  0.173467     1.0
2018-04-08 00:59:22.202   1      6  1.625283     1.0
2018-04-08 02:36:53.221   1      4  0.332900     2.0
2018-04-08 02:56:51.662   1      7  0.372258     2.0
2018-04-08 03:19:11.791   1     10  0.000000     2.0
2018-04-08 02:56:51.662   2      5  0.511591     3.0
2018-04-08 03:27:33.390   2      2  0.340553     3.0
2018-04-08 03:47:59.379   2      9  1.329548     3.0
2018-04-08 05:07:45.751   2      3  0.000000     4.0
```

Now you can use the method you gave doing the first groupby on 'ID_res', keeping both column 'ID' and 'Value', and droping the column 'ID_res' at the end as you don't need it anymore:

```
df = (df.groupby('ID_res', axis=0)['ID','Value'].resample('10min').mean()
        .groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.interpolate())
        .reset_index().drop('ID_res',1))
```

The result looks like:

```
                  Time   ID  Value
0  2018-04-08 00:20:00  1.0    2.0
1  2018-04-08 00:30:00  1.0    3.5
2  2018-04-08 00:40:00  1.0    5.0
3  2018-04-08 00:50:00  1.0    6.0
4  2018-04-08 02:30:00  1.0    4.0
5  2018-04-08 02:40:00  1.0    5.5
6  2018-04-08 02:50:00  1.0    7.0
...
```

In which you don't have resampling between the row 3 and 4 has the 'Gaps' was over 0.86 between these values in the original `df`

Comment: Thank you. One quick question, is it safer to use this too right ? df.groupby('ID_res', axis=0)['ID','Gaps','Value']. I am not interested in Gaps interpolation but I am interested in where , those original gaps of over .86Hrs are still there in correct rows.

Comment: @user3280146 it should not change the result for the columns ID and Value so no problem :)